# What does Urdhva Pundra (Thirunamam) represent?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, symbolism, tilak

Most Hindus who worship Shree Vishnu wear [Urdhva Pundra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdhva_Pundra) (Thirunamam) on their forehead. What does this symbol represent?

Answer (score 3):

As taught to me by my Acharyan, the color white is universally considered a symbol of peace. The twin feet of Our Lord give us peace so we wear them on our forehead to invoke that in us.

Red is universally the symbol of love, kripa.  We are because of His love. We are constantly reminded of that by wearing that. So, our way is of Love and Peace.

Please recognize that this is the explanation from a Jeeyar.

[This](https://jetuk.org/2016/05/26/what-is-oordhwapundra-namam-on-the-forehead/) is also  source link which says the same.

Comment: Thanks Sree, Ok if this is the reason. Then why lord Vishnu itself is wearing his twin feet symbol in this forehead? Is it telling more than this, like symbol of universe creation (e.g. Big bang symbol)?

Comment: @Vijai The tirunamam on the Lord's temples are the representation that it is Lord only and not other deities. The white mark represents Lord Vishnu and the red or sandal mark represents Lakshmi. So, it is Lakshmi and Lord. This is said in Padma Purana.